# In which shared-mailboxes is a security group entered with sendas permissions?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, exchange, security-groups

How can I with powershell in which shared-mailboxes is a security group entered with sendas permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following commands in the EMS to see which shared mailboxes have the `Send As` permissions of a security group:

```
$shared = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails Shared
foreach($s in $shared)
{
$Name = "*" + $s.Name + "*" 
Get-ADPermission -Identity "<Security Group Name>" | where{$_.ExtendedRights -like "*send*" -and $_.User -like $Name}
}
```

The following snapshots which show my test result are for your reference:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem now is the hybrid system. Get-Mailbox no get any result on Exchange Management Shell onPremise. If i open the shell on the cloud i get all shared mailboxes to the Variable but the Get-adpermission not working there even though i'm loading the active directory module.  Any idea?

Comment: Connect to Exchange Online powershell and run the commands post in my new answer.

Comment: Get-RecipientPermission unfortunately also not known.  and get-remotemailbox onPremise not have the -recipientdetails parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$shared = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails Shared
foreach($s in $shared)
{Get-RecipientPermission -Identity "<Security Group Name>" | where{$_.Trustee -eq $s.PrimarySmtpAddress -and $_.AccessRights -like "*SendAs*"}}
```

Comment: Get-RecipientPermission unfortunately also not known. Thanks

Comment: Where do the shared mailboxes and the security group locate in? Cloud or On-prem?

Comment: The shared mailboxes i can get in the cloud only because Get-Mailbox only working in the cloud environment. In the onPremiseShell Get-RecipientPermission not working at all but Get-ADPermission.is working on premise but not in the cloud.  My Idea:  maybe you can get all shared mailboxes in the cloud to a textfile and asked this file onpremise to complete the script with Get-ADPermission e.g.                                                                                        
 Get-Content "C:\sharedMB.txt" |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ADPermission .......

Comment: If so, you could run the command **`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails Shared | Select-Object Name | Export-Csv <Location>\Shared.csv`** in the **EXOL** PowerShell to export a CSV file which includes the names of all shared mailbox.

Comment: Then run the following commands in the **On-prem** Exchange PowerShell to get the shared mailboxes which have the **Send As** permission of the security group: `$shared = Import-Csv <Location of the csv file>\Shared.csv
 foreach($s in $shared){Get-ADPermission -Identity "<Security Group Name>" | where{$_.ExtendedRights -like "*send*" -and $_.User -like $s.Name}}`

Comment: Thats it!  Thank you so much